# Entity Framework Core 2.0 - Run migrations step by step

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

In EF6 I could retrieve migrations and run it step by step.
Is there a way to do something similar in EF Core?

**EF 6 Code**

```
public static void RunMigration(this DbContext context, DbMigration migration, string providerName, string manifest)
{
    var prop = migration.GetType().GetProperty("Operations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (prop != null)
    {
        IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> operations = prop.GetValue(migration) as IEnumerable<MigrationOperation>;
        MigrationSqlGenerator generator = (new DbMigrationsConfiguration()).GetSqlGenerator(providerName);
        var statements = generator.Generate(operations, manifest);
        foreach (MigrationStatement item in statements)
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item.Sql);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [GetPendingMigrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions_GetMigrations_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_) extension method of the `DatabaseFacade` class (returned by `Database` property of the `DbContext`) to get the list of the pending migration names.

Then you can obtain [`IMigrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator) service and use [`Migrate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrator#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Migrations_IMigrator_Migrate_System_String_) method passing each target migration name:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

DbContext db = ...;
var pendingMigrations = db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().ToList();
if (pendingMigrations.Any())
{
    var migrator = db.Database.GetService<IMigrator>();
    foreach (var targetMigration in pendingMigrations)
        migrator.Migrate(targetMigration);
}
```