# Apply all migrations up to specific migration

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

It is possible to apply all migrations by using the [`RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.migrate?view=efcore-2.1) extension method. e.g.

```
if (_ctx.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
{
    //Apply migration
    _ctx.Database.Migrate();
}
```

However, I have a specific requirement to carry out the following migration actions at runtime:

1. Apply migrations up to a certain point
2. Seed some data
3. Apply all remaining migrations (this will remove columns which are no
   longer required after the seeding)

Is there a method that I can use to apply all migrations up to a specific (named) migration at runtime (e.g. an equivalent to the .net Core CLI command [`dotnet ef database update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-database-update))?

Comment: [Entity Framework Core 2.0 - Run migrations step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780598/entity-framework-core-2-0-run-migrations-step-by-step/45781076)