# How can I use EF Core Migrations API directly by code

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

With Entity Framework Core, we can generate C# migration files, containing database information to create tables, columns, indexes, etc… and then we can deploy the database using command line, or with a EF DbContext.

Is there a way to use directly the Migrations API by code to modify a database, without using "real" migrations (without code model or dbContext) ?

I would like to do something like this :

```
var builder = new MigrationBuilder(activeProvider);
builder.CreateTable(
    name: "Table1",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
    });

Apply(builder, connectionString);
```

What should I put in the `Apply` method to create the table in my database ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore.Relational/Migrations/Internal/Migrator.cs uses `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` and `IMigrationCommandExecutor` to execute migration operations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45781076/1859959 might help. If you can make a targetMigration out of the builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went in the EF Core internals, and found a way to use the APIs.

I'm not sure if it is a good idea, or if it will work fine, but it works for a simple case (create table, add column).

First, we need to register some EF Core services :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICurrentDbContext, CurrentDbContext>();
    services.AddScoped<RelationalConnectionDependencies>();
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();

    DbContextOptionsBuilder dbContextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
    dbContextOptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDeploy;Integrated Security=True;");
    services.AddSingleton<IDbContextOptions>(dbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();

    services.AddScoped<MyMigrationRunner>();
}
```

We don't use the DbContext directly, but it seems that it is used internally. We don't need anything specific, we can just register the base DbContext from EF Core.

Also, I used SqlServer specific implementation, I assume it would work with other providers, but I didn't test.

To build the database, I created a Migration class

```
public class MyMigration : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Table1",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            });
    }
}
```

Now I can use the `IMigrationsSqlGenerator` service to generate the SQL commands and apply them to the database

```
public class MyMigrationRunner
{
    private readonly IRelationalConnection connection;
    private readonly IMigrationsSqlGenerator migrationsSqlGenerator;

    public MyMigrationRunner(IMigrationsSqlGenerator migrationsSqlGenerator, IRelationalConnection connection)
    {
        this.migrationsSqlGenerator = migrationsSqlGenerator;
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var migration = new MyMigration();
        var commands = migrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(migration.UpOperations).ToList();
        foreach (var cmd in commands)
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(connection);
        }
    }
}
```